# How to recover original Metamask Wallet after creation of new contract over existing contract?

Tags: private-key

Can view details on Etherscan. Factory reset cellphone and was directed to create new Metamask account, which I did. Now I cannot access my wallet. SECRET Recovery Phrase brings up a different wallet address and this is where I an stuck. Don't know private keys as everything changed and lost them. Help?!